# Raid 0 on two SSDs on Macbook pro Mid 2012 (non retina) running Catalina?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, catalina, ssd, raid

I am using Macbook pro-Mid 2012 (non-retina).
There are two SSDs, one 850 EVO (250 GB) and 860 Pro (256 GB).
Both have Catalina installed and running perfectly. I can switch easily using startup disk in preferences.

860 Pro is installed recently and is fresh and new macOS installation.
Now I want to keep the 860 Pro as my main Catalina booting and use another disk(850 EV)) as RAID 0.

I have read people facing issues with RAID in Catalina, so just wanted to know what are cons and pros if this is done.

Will I face any issues with this, specifically will downloading be a problem if this is done?

Please ask if you have any questions, I have provided most of the information, other than this its i5, 16GB Ram

Comment: What disks will you use as your RAID-0? Generally RAID disks need to be the same size or the RAID will end up as the size of the **smallest** member. So you would end up with *one* (faster) 250GB disk. And RAID-0 has no redundancy so if one of the drives fail you lose **all of the data.** So backups are very important.

Comment: *I want to keep the 860 Pro as my main Catalina booting and use another disk(850 EV)) as RAID 0.*  This makes no sense.  As written, you're saying you  want to use the 850 EVO in a RAID 0 config.  But, [you need a minimum of 2 disks for RAID 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0).  Do you mean to say you want **both** the 850 EVO and 860 Pro in the RAID array?

Comment: You need to cite your sources.  *I have read people facing issues...Will I face any issues....*  What people?  What issues?  This like going to the doctors office and saying "I heard people say that you can get sick if I go outside. What viruses can I get?"  As for downloading - it has exactly nothing to do with your drive.  You can download to anything - a drive, a flash stick, a CD, to a network share, even to memory so the two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: One last thing.... It seems like this is new to you, and I encourage you to experiment and try.  If this is your work computer - I would avoid this like the plague.  It sounds like you are unfamiliar with RAID setups so I don't recommend you venturing into this if this is the computer you use to get your work done.  Experiment with RAID using USB flash drives or external USB before messing around with your boot drive.  RAID 0 is very unforgiving meaning your very next post might be about how to salvage your data.

Comment: "A RAID 0 striped set is all about increasing speed and performance. This type of RAID is a good choice for video editing, multimedia storage, and scratch space for applications, such as Photoshop, that benefit from faster drive access. It's also a good choice for speed demons out there who want to achieve high performance just because they can."


https://www.lifewire.com/use-disk-utility-to-create-a-raid-0-striped-array-2260918

Comment: @Allan I mean you get the idea, I will be erasing one one disk and adding the 860 evo in raid array for a RAID -0 Setup.  Here is a link I found where issues are discussed, I was watching youtube videos in which they are discussing the issues in RAID on catalina. 

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/catalina-on-raid-with-apfs-on-macpro-5-1.2216730/

Comment: As I said I have two boot drives, one of which will be erased in the process and after the RAID Process, there will be one single drive most likely of 500 GB, and will have faster speeds of read and writes.

Answer (score 1):

Revision - it can be done with no cons.

I tried several methods since lesniakrafal did not work directly on my first attempt but after several attempts this does work. Please forgive if I stumble around, I have 25 years using unix but this is my first Mac I got 3 weeks ago.

1. I did try ccc and was not able to do updates or installs.
2. I did manage to install using unix style dd and seem to remember I could do updates, install problems can be overridden with `xattr -cr`  or running `csrutil disable` from installation media. Problem was I had dd'd a 250GB drive to external 2TB with dd back resulted in a 250GB on a 500GB raid0 array. `dd if=/dev/disk5 of=/dev/disk2 bs=64k` where disk5 was the synthesized external install and disk2 was the (virtual raid). This might be useful if you want to copy your current install and possibly you could get updates to work normally using the method I present here after doing a resize.
3. Install to external drive, resize with `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk4s2 499400m`, and dd back does work but again system updates and installs do not work without running csrutil disable from installation usb.
4. You can get a successful install on /dev/disk2 the virtual drive 2 ways. One using the Disk Utility to create the array and end up with a virtual container with no GPT or EFI partition. This runs but updates failed for me so diskutil list should show an EFI partition on disk2. Use lesniakrafal method with GPT assigned and EFI partition included on the raid0 array virtual drive, I did get a successful install with updates.
5. You do not need to download or install any patches, Catalina runs on this model.
   I give all credit to the following page/author where I leave out a few steps and embellish with some details of the install.

https://lesniakrafal.com/install-mac-os-catalina-raid-0/

1. Make a flash drive with Catalina installer.

   - Download with Safari/App Store with a Mac and insert a 16GB USB flash drive.
   - Open a terminal and type `ls /Volumes` to find the new flash drive, mine was /Volumes/NEW\ VOLUME
   - Run `/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/creatinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/NEW\ VOLUME`
   - Eject when done and reboot.
2. Hold down the option key and select the newly created flash/usb installer, you'll do this a lot.
3. Use the top menu bar to open a terminal.
4. Get a list of your current drives.

   `diskutil list`
5. Unmount the drives and destroy the gpt partitions. The internal drives were 0 & 1, 2 was the virtual raid, 3 was nested under 2, and I had the external drive were disk4 and disk5 not used in this example, and disk6 was the installer usb.

   `diskutil unmountDisk disk0
   diskutil unmountDisk disk1
   diskutil unmountDisk disk2
   diskutil unmountDisk disk3
   diskutil unmountDisk disk4
   diskutil unmountDisk disk5
   gpt destroy /dev/disk0
   gpt destroy /dev/disk1
   gpt destroy /dev/disk4` (external disk)

Then follow lesniakrafal instructions

6. Setup the raid array which will have its own EFI partition.

   `diskutil appleRAID create stripe Storage JHFS+ disk0 disk1
   diskutil unmountDisk disk2
   gpt create disk2
   gpt add -t hfs disk2`
7. Exit the terminal and open the disk utility and format the array APFS and named as APFS RAID
8. Exit the terminal and open the disk utility and format the external drive APFS if you are trying dd method.
9. Exit disk utility and install macOS Catalina. This time I got the option to install to the APFS RAID and the EXTERNAL DRIVE so did not follow the install to external dd back to internal method.
10. Install Catalina directly to the raid0 array.
11. Do not install any patches, Catalina will run on mid 2012 MacBook Pro.
12. Then it displays The bless tool was unable to set the current boot disk (we know how to fix that now from the dd attempts). Run the following commands.

    `/sbin/mount -uw /
    mv /usr/standalone/bootcaches.plist /usr/standalone/bootcaches.bak
    csrutil disable`
13. Sometimes there is a disk space low error popup just dismiss & Restart.
14. Installer resources were not found error, Restart and try again (maybe we don't know how to fix that). You may have to reboot several times and during my dd attempts and then one restart here I ran First Aid on the raid disks.
15. Restart to flash installer holding down option key not by automatic boot repair.
16. Run disk FirstAid on the raid drives if you haven't already.
17. Open a terminal and run the following commands again.

    `/sbin/mount -uw /
    mv /usr/standalone/bootcaches.plist /usr/standalone/bootcaches.bak`
18. Important!!!! Reboot and REMOVE INSTALLER FLASH so it only boots to the raid0 array. Then it booted into the new macOS and asks for location, language, Apple ID etc.
19. Reboot normally and Update 2021-007 10.15.7 and Safari.
20. Reboot. Error macOS can't be installed on your computer
21. Reboot with holding the OPTION KEY and flash installer again.
22. Open terminal and run these again.

    `/sbin/mount -uw /
    mv /usr/standalone/bootcaches.plist /usr/standalone/bootcaches.bak`
23. Reboot. Some updates could not be installed automatically. At first it was showed the 2021-007 update which changed to a Device Support Update.
24. Click Update Now. Your Mac is up to date, reboot and it is still up to date, and can install Firefox, woohoo!

25 Run the following commands as per lesniakrafal...

`sudo trimforce enable
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -root /` (did not work for me)

26. Set root password and change to root account.

    `sudo passwd root
    su - root`
27. Final check and fixes from lesniakrafal

    `diskutil list
    diskutil apfs updatePreboot disk3s5
    diskutil apfs deleteVolume disk3s3`

Everything works!
Read speed 914MB/sec and write speed 844MB/sec

Comment: This is cool technically. However, I always have to remind  myself “RAID 0 is short hand for _why let one hardware failure only ruin one device’s data…_”

Answer (score 0):

As the question includes possible cons of using raid0 this is a valid concern. Single point failure is a common concern but a single 500MB SSD is also a single point failure. I would guess with mechanical HHDs you double the risk of failure due the the mechanical drive mechanism but SSD do not have a mechanical drive mechanism. SSD failure seems to be related to the number of times they can be r/w or written. If just considering this aspect then a single 500MB drive would have the same expected lifetime as 2 x 250MB drives. As people who work in an enterprise environment then we are comparing RAID0 to RAID1, RAID10, RAID01, RAID5, or RAID6 all of which have some redundancy. For the regular Joe who has a single drive and backs up his important data to an external drive or the cloud the difference between a single 500MB drive and a 2 x 250MB raid0 may be negligible. Consider also the preponderance of utilities begging almost forcing users to backup their data free to the cloud and built into the OS. Though I agree there is no redundancy with raid0, neither is there any for a system with a single drive.

Answer (score -1):

I had luck getting Catalina to run on RAID 0 with Macbook Pro mid 2012 by installing Catalina to an external drive, and then using the flash installer or booting the external drive to create the RAID 0 array on duplicate internal disks with disk utility (click File/RAID Assitant). After creating the array, if you try to install it will show the RAID array as greyed out and not allow install. I also tried the manual method and the RAID 0 array didn't show up at all. Then copy your running external installation to the RAID array with Carbon Copy Cloner.

This will boot fine but the problem is you can't update the system and when you go to install programs they won't install without running `xattr -cr /path/to/application.app` on the install files. You can update your external drive and CCC back to the internal RAID 0 array, but for me it isn't worth the trouble. Other than those 2 problems it seemed to work normally.

I actually did this twice and the first time I had problems getting terminal permissions to run 'ls' even as root. I did some installs on the external drive copied again and some problems went away but still couldn't update without going back to the external drive.

I have not tried `csrutil disable` yet but might be worth a try to get updates to work.

I tried dd from an unmounted internal disk to unmounted external disk with the idea I could dd back to an internal raid0 array but boot was not successful (work in progress). Here are some links to pages that some people have had success with...

https://lesniakrafal.com/install-mac-os-catalina-raid-0/

https://osxdaily.com/2019/02/13/fix-app-damaged-cant-be-opened-trash-error-mac/
See xattr -cr /path/to/application.app

You might look into methods that use Clover boot loader or `micropatcher.sh`.

So in short, the problems you may run into are that updates may not work and it may be more difficult but not impossible to install applications.