# Can’t change startup disk to be a RAID 0 disk

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, catalina, raid

I just successfully merged two exact same size and model internal SSDs in my MacBook Pro mid-12 but now I am forced to run OS Catalina off of an external hard drive. I want to be able to run OS Catalina off of my RAID 0 hard drives and discount my external which I can’t have run/boot my computer longterm.

Any suggestions? Is there a fix or patcher I can download?

Comment: Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396218/raid-0-on-two-ssds-on-macbook-pro-mid-2012-non-retina-running-catalina